# Django file upload form constructor explained

Tags: python, django

As I go through Django tutorial, I'm confused about the way the form is constructed, here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads) where the following code is from:

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UploadFileForm

# Imaginary function to handle an uploaded file.
from somewhere import handle_uploaded_file

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES) 
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Question: Where can I find the constructor declaration of `UploadFileForm`?

Comment: Part of the confusion may be that there are not exactly constructors in Python; there is a class object's `__new__` method (basically the constructor) and the more widely overriden `__init__` method. Check out the Django source code linked by @doniyor; your `UploadFileForm` subclasses `forms.Form`, which inherits from the `BaseForm` class. On instantiation, all of these cal the `__init__` method of the `BaseForm` class object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the constructor declaration: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L72-L98

Question answered?